# firefox , IE6 and opera have different things to show

Tags: php, html, css

my code which I am going to paste here  shows different results in FF, IE6 and Opera.

The difference between results from FF and Opera is the amount of space shown above (in sky color) and below (in white color) the horizontal menu. In the case of IE6, the difference from the result of  FF is the amount of space (white color) shown below the horizontal menu. How can I get all 3 browsers to show the same result i.e the current result from FF ?

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>fffffff</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
 <div class="header_inside">
 <div class="logo">
 <img src="img/img_flwr.png" width="224px" height="162px" >
 </div> <!-- end of class logo-->

  <div class="chat">
  <a href="phponline/client.php"  target="_blank"><img src="img/img_flwr.png" width="124px" height="62px"></a>

  </div>


  <div class="clear">
  </div>  


  <div class="name">
   <marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="RIGHT" scrollamount='5' scrolldelay='25' >

      CODE ARROW
 </marquee> 

  </div> -->


     <div id="slides">
    <img src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="Img 1" width="815px" height="268px" />

</div>  


  <div class="clear">
  </div>  
  <br>

</div> <!-- end of class header_inside-->
 </div> <!-- end of header-->


   <div class="menu_h">
   <div class="menu_h_inside">
   <br>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" id="home_nav" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery_core.php?page=1" id="image_gallery_nav">Photo Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Career</a></li>


<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear:left"/>
</div> <!-- end of class menu_h_inside-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css is:

```
/* CSS Document */
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;

}
body{
    width: 1160px;
    /*background:#BFFDC4 !important;*/
    margin-left: 20px;
    /*border:4px solid red;*/
}

#frame {

 /*width: 710px;*/
 width: 1125px;
 /*BORDER:12PX SOLID RED;*/
 /*border:7px solid green;*/
}

#header{
position:relative:
display:block;
/*border:10px solid green;*/
width:1160px;
background:#9DD4FF;

}
.header_inside{


}


body#home a#home_nav,
body#image_gallery a#image_gallery_nav
 {

background-color:#0b75b2 !important;
}


.logo{
position:relative;
left:3px;
top:3px;
float:left;

/*border: 8px solid  #F2AC4E;*/

}
.chat{
position:relative;

float:left;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:15px;
/*border:13px solid red;*/

}

.chat img:hover{




}

.clear{

clear:both;

}
.name{
position:relative;
display:block
clear:both;

width:300px;
height:50px;
MARGIN-TOP:75PX;

background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFF80;

font-size:40px;
}



#slides{
position:relative;
left:300px;
MARGIN-top:-180px;
FLOAT:LEFT;


}


/* horizontal menu_h css begins*/

.menu_h{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:20px;
    width: 1145px;
    /*border:5px solid yellow;*/
     }

  .menu_h ul{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;}

.menu_h ul li{
    display: inline;
 }

.menu_h ul li a{
    float: left; text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10.5px 44.6px;
    /*background-color: #333; EDITED BY ME */ 
  background-color:#C7A781;
   border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

  }

.menu_h ul li a:visited{

    color: white;}

.menu_h ul li a:hover, .menu_h ul li .current{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#0b75b2;}


  /* horizontal menu_h css ended */


.menu_h_inside{
    margin-left:1px;
    /*margin-top:7px;*/
}
```

IMAGES should be used in appropriate places.

Thanks in advance.
Istiaque Ahmed
Bangladesh

Comment: it might work better to just paste the code you're using into pastebin.com instead of here on SO.

Comment: Please reformat the code, it's unreadable!

Comment: 1. Post the relevant code. I doubt too many people want to debug your whole mess of HTML and CSS here. What styles control the spacing in question. 2. Post a link to what it's supposed to look like

Comment: @jpea, @CAFxX, @Cfreak i understand the problem, since  the time of submitting the question I am looking for the solution that will allow me to show up in the page the source code properly... I know there is some way to code paste in this site so that exactly the source code and not any results out of the code should show up but can't find that out now. please tell me what to do i.e. typing certain code at the start and end of the source code.  pastebin.com ?? seems to be complex to handle, or i donno ..

Comment: @jpea, @CAFxX, @Cfreakwow, I clicked on 'link' below my posted question and now it has become what I wanted.

Comment: @jpea i have made the code clear now, can u  make any suggestion, please?

Comment: @Cfreak , i have made the code readable, do u have anything to suggest plz?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely caused by the browser default stylesheets being all over the place. You should consider adding in a good CSS reset before spending a lot of time trying to debug the problem. This one is from the guy that came up with the first universal reset. It works pretty well.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @Brent Friar, i used the code in the page. the prob is still there.

Comment: You next step would then be to use Firebug, FF Web Developer, or Chrome Inspect Element to see exactly what CSS is being applied to he various problem areas. It is also possible that you will need to make browser specific style sheets. BTW - does your client require IE6 support? If not, I would very seriously consider dropping it completely.

Comment: @Brent Friar, prob is with Opera. I tried with opera dragonflyer but cannot understand why the two spaces above and below the horizontal menu change ... trying to discard IE6. dragonflye shows the relevant area of a code segment.. how can i understand why the space gets increased?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat i thought u might be the right person to be invited to solve the prob though you haven't yet participated here.

Comment: @Pekka, i thought u might be the proper person to be invited to solve this prob despite the fact that you have not yet participated here.

Comment: Someone doesn't like your question for some reason. Users can downvote without leaving a reason though it is good etiquette to tell someone why you are down voting so they can either fix the question/answer or learn why their question/answer is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your doctype is incorrect and you are in quirks mode. Change your doctype to this     `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`     and see where we stand.

Make sure you follow Firefox or Opera first. Then look to see how IE screws things up before you try and "fix" anything. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right.

Comment: it worked for the sky color part above  the horizontal menu. thanks a lot for that. but what about the extra space shown in Opera below the horizontal menu ?